# Initializing globals with variables in C

Tags: c, global-variables, static-variables

I having the following variables defined at the top of my file right after my `#include` directives;

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;
```

But I get a compile time error.  I know that global variables implicitly have static storage duration, but I'm not sure how or if this is related to the cause of this error.

Comment: You have to use constant expressions that can be fully evaluated at compile time.  The value in `a` is not a constant (even if you add `const`).  You could use `int *p = &a;` — the address of `a` is a compile time (link time) constant.  If you really need to initialize global variables from more complex expressions, you need C++.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, global variables implicitly have static storage duration. This is because global variables are initialised during compile time. So this is precisely the reason why you are getting an error.

From **C99 Standard 6.7.8**:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

To get past this rule, you could use the following "trick".

```
int a = 5;
int b;

int main()
{
  b = a;
  //rest of code goes here.
}
```

Comment: I know this.  I'm wondering why that's the case.  I guess what I'm asking is why the compiler requires it to be that way.

Comment: In this way, initialising code for the global variables is not needed. The program begins with the global variables pre-initialised. This would not be possible if you used the code you linked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

A constant expression is needed to initialize a global variable and even though `a` seems perfectly constant to us in this context, the compiler does not see it this way.

As I read the code, the goal is to have `a` and `b` initialized with the same value defined at a single point.

One way to accomplish this is to define the common initializer for `a` and `b`:

```
#define INIT 5
int a = INIT;
int b = INIT;
```