# Error when initializing global pointer to dynamic memory

Tags: c, gcc, initialization, static-memory-allocation

I was writing a program that involves `malloc` to create a global array. I tried this (outside `main()`, of course):

```
int *arr=malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

In the GCC compiler, the following error is flashed:

```
main.c:4:10: error: initializer element is not constant
 int *arr=(int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
          ^
```

I tried this on Dev-C++, but no such error interrupted the compilation. 
What is meant by the error and why is it specific to GCC?

Comment: Dev-C++ compiles C++, not C.

Comment: related; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287786/initializing-globals-with-variables-in-c

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory - the value you're trying to set `arr` isn't a constant. You could set `arr` to `NULL` and then do the memory allocating inside `main`. Also, you don't need to cast the results from `malloc`

Comment: @Quentin Oops. You're right.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Yeah I've come across that before... I have no idea why my programming professor insists that I should.

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer The cast is required for C++, so your professor may be getting confused regarding what the two languages allow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables declared at file scope must have initializers that are compile time constants.  A function call is considered executable code and cannot exists outside of a function.

The best way to handle this would be to initialize the pointer to NULL and perform the `malloc` in the `main` function.

The reason you're not seeing an error with DEV-C++ is because it is a C++ compiler and C++ allows file scope variables to be initialized with function calls.

Answer (score 1):

You may not initialize variables with the static storage duration with non-constant expressions in C (but this may be done in C++).

So you need to split the declaration of the pointer and its initialization with the address of dynamically allocated memory.